# how to check empty value from array?

Tags: php, arrays, json

OK. So i have a `json_encoded string` like this:

```
{"MostViews":"1","Tags":"","PhotoSize":""}
```

Decoded it so it looks like this:

```
$specificdetail = json_decode('{"MostViews":"1","Tags":"","CanvasSize":""}',true);
print_r(specificdetail);

// printed array 
    Array
    (
        [MostViews] => 1
        [Tags] => 
        [PhotoSize] => 
    )
```

Now you can see in the array there are two items Tags and PhotoSize are empty.

and My Requirement is that:

I am creating a `dynamic div` which will be visible if i got item with a value. I mean item should have any value. if all have empty then i will not show the `div`.

So i just did the basic thing to extract the array value:

```
$counter=0;
foreach($specificdetail as $specificd)
{
    if(!empty($specificd)){
        $counter++;
    }
} 
if(!empty($counter))
{
   echo "<div>Detail:</div>";
}
```

Now it is giving me this `Fatal Error`:

> Fatal error: Cannot access empty property

And i have also tried to use `key=>value` pair and checked the value but same result.

Can anybody tell me whats wrong with this? I know that many questions related to this fatal error have been asked before and i have checked few of them but non of them helped me?

Please Help.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me, are you sure its this part of the code that triggers the fatal error ?

Comment: @ClémentMalet - `if(!empty($specificd)` it gives me fatal error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. so i just did a little change in my `if` condition and also used the `key=>value` pair

```
foreach($specificdetail as $key=>$specificd)
        {
            if($specificd !== '' ){
                $counter++;
            }
        }
echo $counter; // it gives me 1 which is true because there is only one item is not empty
```

BTW thanks everybody to giving your precious time.

Answer (score 0):

first json decode your code with `json_decode()`  function then ,

```
$old_count=count($array);

$new_count=count(array_filter($array));

$number_of_empty_values=($old_count - $new_count);

echo $number_of_empty_values;
```

Comment: you are doing extra work here, getting number of empty value and compare with total count from main array. BTW thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
if($counter != 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello just put this code

```
$empty=array();
$feed=array();
$k=0;
$count_feeed=0;
$count_empty=0;
foreach($specificdetail as $key=>$val){
  if($val != ""){
    $feed[$k][$key]=$val;
    $count_feeed++;
 }else{
   $empty[$k][$key]=$val;
   $count_empty++;
  }
  $k++;
 }
echo "<br/> Total feeding element: $count_feed;";
echo "<br/> Total empty element: $count_empty;";
echo "Your feeding array which is not empty.";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($feed);
echo "<br/>";
echo "Your empty array which is empty.";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($empty);
echo "<br/>Enjoy....";
```

Let me know if any bug